# What's a good threshold for relevance when syntax highlighting with highlight.js?

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, highlight.js

The wonderful [highlight.js](http://highlightjs.org/) library provides a `highlightAuto` function which attempts to detect the language of the code that you pass it. It returns a `relevance` value, but the [docs](http://highlightjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#highlightauto-value-languagesubset) for that function offer no more guidance than that this is an "integer value".

I'd like to do syntax highlighting on some code, but only when I'm very confident that highlight.js has figured out the language. Is there a threshold I can set for the relevance value, either an absolute threshold or as a function of lines of code?

Answer (score 1):

Recently answered a similar question: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/highlightjs/lOagvNMi9mk/rLbHB6mkvOAJ

To put it in the context of your question, highlight.js doesn't detect languages. For that we would need much more comprehensive grammars and rather big lists of known keywords and stdlib names. But we're constrained by size and maintainability. So the relevance only shows which of the syntaxes would provide more useful highlighting.